# Как вывести первые строки всех таблиц одной БД в MS SQL?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Итак, мой вопрос заключается в том что я хочу вывести первую строку каждой таблицы единой БД(в моем случае это Northwind), где ID = 1, пытаюсь сделать это используя декларирование курсора, может у кого есть какие догадки?

Я немного пытался что-то придумать, но поскольку новичок в изучении языка запросов, дальше дело не идет

```
DECLARE test_cursor CURSOR
    FOR SELECT * FROM Northwind WHERE some_id = 1;
```

---

Нашел решение, вопрос закрыт, нет личного мнения

Comment: совет - пройдитесь по таблице(-ам) с метаданными и динамически создайте запросы для всех таблиц и выполните их... Кстати таблицы с информацией о столбцах и ключах помогут проверить во всех ли таблицах существует столбец `ID`...

Comment: @MaxU Вы имеете ввиду сделать для каждой таблицы запрос SELECT*FROM some_table WHERE some_id = 1; ?

Comment: @Bohdan, да, динамически создать SQL скрипт и запустить его...

Comment: @MaxU увы, мне такое тоже не подходит, поскольку данная БД насчитывает около 15 таблиц и это сказывается на быстродействии и загружености оперативки

Comment: Напишите 15 явных скрипта и запустите их. 15 это не 15 тысяч. Вполне приемлемо вызвать их

Comment: У вас цель какая: вывести первые строки всех таблиц или научиться использовать курсор?

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'select top 1 * from ?'
```

Comment: Скорей всего нет, мне запрещено использовать EXECUTE в данном случае, дело не в работе с процедурами

Comment: @Bohdan - а в чём именно дело? Опишите все требования и запреты в вопросе.